# Where is my error in this proof that the uniform limit of Riemann integrable functions is Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, proof-verification

I am sure there is a major flaw in my proof, but I cannot find it.  I would be very happy if someone could point it out for me.  Note that I am not looking for any hints or solutions.  Below, $LR$ and  $UR$ mean lower Riemann integral and upper Riemann integral.

$\textbf{Problem.}$  Let $\{f_{n}\}$ be a sequence of bounded functions that converge uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$.  If each $f_n$ is Riemann integrable over $[a,b]$, show that $f$ is also Riemann integrable over $[a,b]$.

$\textbf{Proof.}$ We always have $LR\int_{a}^{b}f\leq UR\int_{a}^{b}f$.  Let $\epsilon>0$.  Then there exists an $N$ such that $f_{n}-\epsilon<f<f_{n}+\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$ and $x\in [a,b]$.  So if $n\geq N$, then

$LR\int_{a}^{b}f=$sup$\{\int_{a}^{b}\phi$ | $\phi$ is a step function and $\phi\leq f\}\geq$ sup$\{\int_{a}^{b}\phi$ | $\phi$ is a step function and $\phi\leq f_{n}-\epsilon\}=\int_{a}^{b}(f_{n}-\epsilon)=\int_{a}^{b}f_{n}-\epsilon(b-a)$.

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary we have $LR\int_{a}^{b}f\geq\int_{a}^{b}f_{n}$.  Similarly, using $f\leq f_{n}+\epsilon$, we get $UR\int_{a}^{b}f\leq\int_{a}^{b}f_{n}$.  Hence $LR\int_{a}^{b}f\geq UR\int_{a}^{b}f$, which completes the proof.

Comment: Why do you think there is a flaw?

Comment: A potential problem is that, whilst $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, $n$ is not. $n$ is chosen dependent on $\epsilon$, so that once you send $\epsilon \to 0$ you should also send $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Doesn't the proof imply that $\int_{a}^{b}f=\int_{a}^{b}f_{n}$ for all $n\geq N$?

Comment: @RhysSteele Yes, you are right.

Comment: No. Let me illustrate the problem with just one side of the inequality. You have shown that $LR \int_a^b f \geq \int_a^b f_n - \epsilon (b-a)$ for a fixed $n$ and $\epsilon$ and then to conclude you say that $\epsilon$ is arbitrary so you can write $LR \int_a^b f \geq \int_a^b f_n$. But to do this you have sent $\epsilon \to 0$ and hence may have taken an $\epsilon$ small enough that the fixed value of $n$ no longer works.

Comment: @RhysSteele My first comment was meant for Eric Wolfsey, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You can salvage the proof by concluding from $ \int f_n +\epsilon(b-a)\geq UR(f)\geq LR(f)\geq \int f_n -\epsilon(b-a)$, that $|UR(f)-LR(f)|<2\epsilon(b-a)$. Then let $\epsilon\to0$.

Comment: @HGLandcaster Oh cool, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary we have $LR\int_{a}^{b}f\geq\int_{a}^{b}f_{n}$.

$\epsilon$ starts out arbitrary, but at this point of the proof, you have fixed $\epsilon$, and chosen an $N$ and an $n$ based on it. You can let $\epsilon$ go to zero, but then you have a different $f_n$. So you can't say  $LR\int_{a}^{b}f\geq\int_{a}^{b}f_{n}$. You have to say $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (LR\int_{a}^{b}f-\int_{a}^{b}f_{n})\geq0$.

Comment: I'll close this since I don't think there is anything else to add.